# Where can you get additional build orders for Starcraft 2's YABOT map and how can I load them in the multiplayer version?

Tags: starcraft-2, sc2-build-order

I tried YABOT on the battle net map list with a friend, but the terran build order list seemed quite lackluster. I tried finding more build orders around the web but had no such luck. I couldn't even find how to load one up.

So, do you know where I can find those resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too long ago, [sc2builds.com](http://www.sc2builds.com/), a website with YABOT build orders went up!

Comment: We just added the multiplayer encodings to sc2builds.com ^_^

Comment: @xorpwnz You guys rock

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anyone posting YABOT build orders online, but I do know that you can create them from their [website](http://www.xorpwnz.com/YABOT/index.html).

I'll even build one for you:

> 100 [i] General ZvT | 11 | Tzenes | Standard 2 base Muta build.  Your first larval injection should spawn right around when your Metabolic Boost finishes [/i]  [s] 9 100 0 -1 1 1 31 0  | 14 100 0 -1 1 0 35 0  | 14 200 0 -1 1 0 41 0  | 16 100 0 -1 1 1 31 0  | 16 100 100 -1 1 3 42 0  | 17 125 0 -1 1 0 35 1  | 16 150 0 -1 1 1 32 0  | 21 50 0 -1 1 1 35 0  | 22 100 0 -1 1 1 31 0  | 22 300 0 -1 1 0 36 0  | 24 150 100 -1 1 2 3 0  [/s]

---

To run it:

1. Editing the YabotSettings.sc2bank file with Notepad and inserting custom build order from Online YABOT Build Editor then saving.
2. Opening a YABOT map with Galaxy Editor.
3. Running the map via Galaxy Editor.

Comment: Where do you put this? Also, where did you learn this BO?

Comment: @Kenji I'm going to tell you the same thing Arthur Rubinstein said when asked how to get to Carnegie Hall: Practice...

Comment: So that means you defined it through practice? Also, my doubt on how to run the build order is more on the multiplayer map (the one you select in the battle.net list) than on the local, single-player one.

Comment: @Ken I learned this BO the old fashion way.  On reference to the multiplayer map: xorpwnz [explains](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyz7dRKX_Ag) that the online YABOT has limited memory so he didn't make it easily editable for BO.